# How do I avoid resource path conflicts in Wicket?

Tags: wicket, url-mapping

I can't get resource paths to work properly in Wicket. What I do is that I have two resources.

- ProfileResource : `/profiles`
- ProfileHistoryResource : `/profiles/{username}/history`

The way I mount the two resources to these paths are as below.

```
   mountResource("/profiles", new ResourceReference("profilesResource") {
        ProfilesResource resource = new ProfilesResource();

        @Override
        public IResource getResource() {
            return resource;
        }

    });

    mountResource("/profiles/{username}/history", new ResourceReference("profilesHistoryResource") {
        ProfilesHistoryResource resource = new ProfilesHistoryResource();

        @Override
        public IResource getResource() {
            return resource;
        }

    });
```

However, this does not work. Once I introduce the `/profiles/{username}/history` resource things just stop working and I get the following error when I attempt to load `/profiles/testuser/history`:

> No suitable method found. URL 'profiles/testuser/rentalaccesses' and HTTP
>   method GET

What am I doing wrong here? Why does these mappings not work?

**ProfilesResource**

```
public class ProfilesResource extends GenericRestResource {

    @MethodMapping(value = "/{username}", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public String get(String username) {
        return "success";
    }
```

**ProfilesHistoryResource**

```
public class ProfilesHistoryResource extends GenericRestResource {

    @MethodMapping(value = "/", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public String get(String username) {
        return "success";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache Wicket (core) doesn't support `{placeholder}`. It supports `${mandatory}` and `#{optional}`. You definitely cannot use `{..}` with WebApplication#mountResource()`.

WicketStuff RestAnnotations supports `@MethodMapping` and co.